# Allow access to RackSpace database from Vagrant box

Tags: percona, connectivity, network

we have two developers using Vagrant (which has it's own internal ip like: 10.0.2.0/24). On RackSpace we have a percona database instance. We would like to allow read/write access to that database from those vagrant boxes. I've never done this from vagrant boxes and was hoping someone could lend support.

The below commands are what I've issued thus far:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 10.0.2.0/24 --dport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 3306 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

sudo invoke-rc.d iptables-persistent save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to find out what external IP address the Vagrant boxes NAT to:

[What is my IP - Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ip&rlz=1C1LENP_enUS492US492&oq=what%20is%20my%20ip&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6560j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Then add an iptables rule for that IP address.

Then you will want to grant access from your MySQL database to the host (The Vagrant box)

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'user'@'vagrantboxremotehost'
IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

You can also use

```
TO 'user'@'%'
```

To allow from any IP, but that is not recommended.